# MSSQL slow stored proc on first run, uncached indexes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Have a 20GB database in SQL Server 2014 behind an IIS web application - DB is queried 24/7 so it's never inactive and auto-close is off but there's a manually-triggered "daily work queue" stored procedure which runs inconsistently during the first execute.

When it's used in the morning for the first time it runs slowly - if you wait, execute again it's back to an immediate response.  Minimal other loads on the server at the same time, page life expectancy is healthy and should have necessary indexes to support this query - or at least no additional indexes are being recommended.

Been trying to approach this as a query optimisation problem and getting nowhere, so began exploring other ideas.

Restored DB from backup onto local dev server - first execution is slow, the second execution is fast and see the large (500mb+) indexes loaded via sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors - if I run DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS to simulate everything being unloaded from the buffer, next execution will be slow, can watch the indexes being cached, which point it executes quickly.

Seems to fit the pattern we're experiencing and doesn't seem unreasonable to assume MSSQL might uncache data that's not been used for 10+ hours.

Have I missed something more obvious?  Assuming I'm on the right path, can't be the first person to run across this issue so must be an elegant solution out there...

Comment: SQL Server never spontaneously evicts pages from the buffer pool. They're removed on a LRU basis for more recent pages based on memory pressure. If, in those 10 hours, you read more data than will fit in the memory of your server, the existing data will indeed have left the buffer pool and new I/O is necessary to get it back. There is a solution as simple as it is elegant (though possibly hard to execute): install more memory, preferably enough to have every single byte of your database in memory all the time.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to know - think I need to review the existing indexes and see if any of the less specialised ones would offer acceptable performance so we're not forced into loaded a large complex index for just this part of the system

Answer (score 0):

If your "daily work queue" change the data. Then index need to be rebuild and reload in the cache. Is the same as start an old car you need to wait a little bit.

What I do is plan those "work" at night and also program some basic query so index are load in the cache.

Also check your hardware (disk, memory) the first time you run the query the db has to bring the data from disk (slow) and store it in memory (fast but small size).

Comment: The work queue doesn't change data, just reads existing data & returns outstanding tasks.   Trialling executing the stored proc before we "need" it but feels like an ugly workaround.